# I'm trying to install ubuntu on acer 5349

Tags: system-installation

Well I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 on an Acer 5349 laptop every time I plug in my live USB flash drive and boot to Ubuntu I get this message on a black screen saying

```
syslinux 4.07 edd 2013-07-25 copyright (c) 1994-2013 h. Peter anvin et al
```

also I'm not in Ubuntu it's when you turn on the computer and boot to live USB and it does not pass that message and I'm trying to replace windows 7 home with Ubuntu 12.04.4 my friend given his old laptop to me so any help will be great oh forgot to say his windows 7 not working it boots to recovery and crashes to a error code so that's why I'm try to put Ubuntu on.

What can I do to fox this?

Answer (score 0):

The Live image on your USB pendrive is NOT proper somehow. 
It's a first recommendation to do a USB Live from Ubuntu Using `Startup Disk Creator`. Yon will need to feed it with ubuntu.iso image file. **Be sure that `md5sum` checksum matches to the original one.**

For the guidance please read [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

As an alternative way you can create Live USB by [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
The idea the same, but it works on everything: Linux, Windows, Mac.